# How can I increment BigDecimal in java through for loop?

Tags: java

How can I increment BigDecimal in java through for loop?
This is the codes that I am currently running and I don't understand why it won't increment the BigDecimal instances

```
package app;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private List<BigDecimal> ticketQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> someNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test() {

        ticketQuantity.add(new BigDecimal(0));
        ticketQuantity.add(new BigDecimal(0));
        ticketQuantity.add(new BigDecimal(0));
        ticketQuantity.add(new BigDecimal(0));

        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        System.out.println(ticketQuantity);

        int i = 0;
        for (BigDecimal x : ticketQuantity) {
            x.add(new BigDecimal(someNumber.get(i)));
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(ticketQuantity);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

What did I miss? I am hoping that `someNumber would equals to [10, 10, 10, 10]` but then `[0, 0, 0, 0]` is printed :(

Comment: BigDecimal is Immutable. Read the api.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) represents:

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers

The [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) means you can't modify an instance. The `add` method will return a *new* `BigDecimal`. If you want to change the value in the list, you will have to go through the loop by index and call `List.set` with the index to replace and the result of `BigDecimal.add`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ticketQuantity.size(); i++) {
    ticketQuantity.set(i, ticketQuantity.get(i).add(someNumber.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: can you give me code examples? But then I want to increment the previous value, set will basically overwrite it with the new value

Answer (score 2):

As explained in other answer, `add()` method will return a new `BigDecimal` and wouldn't modify the original instance due to `BigDecimal` being immutable so you need to do as below,

```
int i = 0;
for (BigDecimal x : ticketQuantity) {
    x = x.add(new BigDecimal(someNumber.get(i)));
    ticketQuantity.set(i, x);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated BigDecimal is an immutable class. The method `BigDecimal#add` actually returns another instance of `BigDecimal`, doesn't update the operand `BigDecimal` object. To achieve your object, you can try the following way:

```
public class Test {
    private List<BigDecimal> ticketQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> someNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test() {

        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        someNumber.add("10");
        System.out.println(ticketQuantity);

        for (String x : someNumber) {
            ticketQuantity.add(new BigDecimal(x));
        }

        System.out.println(ticketQuantity);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```